# How to download the content from server in resume mode in iOS Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, nsurlconnection

Am downloading the Huge amount of content from server in iOS Mobile app.
For downloading the content am following the NSUrlConnectionDelegate Methods.
// code which I have implemented for connection delegate methods

```
-(void)downloadWithNsurlconnection{
dirToCreate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject],rootName];
_fileMangr= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:zipFileAtUrl         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];
NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self     startImmediately:YES];
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
[receivedData setLength:0];
expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
[receivedData appendData:data];
float progressive = (float)[receivedData length] / (float)expectedBytes;
[_updatingProgress setProgress:progressive];
//    NSLog(@"Progress... %.2f",progressive);
}
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
}
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
self.updatingProgress.progress = 1.0;
NSString *dataFileName = nil;
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithString:[zipFileAtUrl absoluteString]];
NSArray *dataLinkArr = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
dataFileName = [dataLinkArr lastObject];
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
BOOL isDir=YES;
NSError *error1 = nil;

if (zipFileAtUrl!=nil) {

}
else{
    NSLog(@"Files are not available in server");
}
if(![_fileMangr fileExistsAtPath:dirToCreate isDirectory:&isDir])
{
    if(![_fileMangr createDirectoryAtPath:dirToCreate withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error1])
    {
    }
    else{
        NSString *localFilePath = [dirToCreate stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
        if ([receivedData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES]) {
            NSLog(@"data file downloaded in directory");
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"failed dat downloading");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
    NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:rootName];
    NSError *error1;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error1];
    NSString *localFilePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:dataFileName];
    if ([receivedData writeToFile:localFilePath atomically:YES]) {
        NSLog(@"data file downloaded");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Not save in documetns folder");
    }
}
[self extractSingleActivityAtindex:activityIndx];
}
```

**Note:**

For example, If the process is going on, when the net has been disconnected or net has been slow the downloading process has been stopped
Here, how to do the resume downloading process

All these functionalists i have implemented in a separate view controller class.
And let me know more details for implementing the same functionality, when the app is in background mode.
The downloading functionality process should be continue until the files downloading process has been completed.

Answer (score 1):

NSURLConnection doesn't provide the feature of pause and resume the download, instead use NSURLSession, it provides the feature to resume, pause and cancel the download process.

```
[yourTask suspend] // to pause the task.
[yourTask resume]; // to resume the task.
[yourTask cancel]; // to cancel the task.
```

Here is an important link for [NSURLSession](http://sysmagazine.com/posts/209736/).

Comment: I don't want to do the resume in manually. Am using to download the NSURLConnectionDelegate Methods. If the net has been disconnected. Downloading process automatically stops. Let us know how to handle this scenario

Comment: Need to know, how you are handling network changes (I guess reachability class from Apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html ). So whenever you get a notification or an event is triggered to indicate that network is down/up. Just throw a local notification and handle it in your Network Manager (class which initialises request and interacts with server). If network is down pause the task, and if the network is back again resume the task.